# How do I upgrade python 2.7.8 to 2.7.9 in Anaconda without conflicting other components in its environment?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

After successful installation of Anaconda on Windows 7 I realized the default Python version is 2.7.8. However I need 2.7.9. So how do I upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot update Python in the root environment of Anaconda on Windows. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29238416/161801.

Answer (score 2):

Your `anaconda` installation ships its own package manager `conda`. You can use it for updating python packages and also the python interpreter.

To update the python interpreter in your default environment, all you have to do is executing the command below from command line:

```
conda update python
```

Comment: Hmh, weird. Does `conda update python --no-deps`, followed by a `conda update python` work?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate that. I ran the command
and following packages got updated

`pip:        1.5.6-py27_0 --> 6.0.8-py27_0
setuptools: 5.8-py27_0   --> 14.3-py27_0`

`conda-env: 2.1.3-py27_0
conda:     3.7.0-py27_0 --> 3.10.0-py27_0
requests:  2.4.1-py27_0 --> 2.6.0-py27_0`

However `lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:79` seems to be creating a problem. Error I get is -- `InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.`

And the version still shows as `python                    2.7.8`

Comment: I guess the problem is with urllib3 as it is unable to call SSL. with 2.7.8 version of python.

Comment: Yes, it seems that you cannot update `requests`, before installing python `2.7.9`. That's why I proposed to try updating only `python` without dependencies first. Have you tried that already?

Comment: Yes, I tried command `conda update python --no-deps` but fails.

Comment: @Nimish - Well, now it's getting more difficult I guess. Unfortunately, I don't have a windows box to try. Can you edit the full error message into your question? I would try to downgrade `requests` back again: `conda install requests=2.4.1`, then try again to update python without deps. If that doesn't work, you could temporarily uninstall `requests` and see if it works (highly speculative).

Answer (score 0):

Install newest version of Anaconda from their website. This will upgrade your Anaconda and python as well. Also, uninstall the previous version of Anaconda.