# Upgrade Anaconda Python version

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to upgrade Anaconda Python version from 3.4 to 3.5 within cmd (Command Prompt) on Windows operating system. How can I do this?

If I do as in [the docs](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#updating-from-older-anaconda-versions):

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

The Python version remains as is (3.4).

Comment: Which platform? (On Windows, you need to either create a new environment or uninstall the old version, then do a clean install of Anaconda 2.4). Did you read [the docs](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#updating-from-older-anaconda-versions)?

Comment: Read their docs. It's on like the first page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating Anaconda's root Python to newer minor version on Windows does nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220236/updating-anacondas-root-python-to-newer-minor-version-on-windows-does-nothing)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following updates the Python version:

```
conda install python=3.5
```

Comment: I do not understand. Is this not a complete anwser?

Comment: It is, but please edit your question with the platform you're using this on. Windows, Mac, Linux?

Comment: Ok, fixed it. Thank you for your help.